# How to use Convert.ChangeType() when conversionType is decimal and input is "40.00"

Tags: c#, .net, generics, decimal

I mean, I want to convert this:

```
string a = "40.00";
Convert.ChangeType(a, typeof(decimal))
```

the result is a decimal value of "4000"

the problem is that the convert call is in a very abstract generic method in a xmlToObject Converter. I don't want to add programmatically lot's of different exceptions to convert correctly.

regards Chris

Comment: Does "40,00" convert correctly?

Comment: You guys need to change your culture man...

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The decimal point might not be represented by the period character in your current culture.

In general, when performing culture-invariant conversions, it's best to specify [CultureInfo.InvariantCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx) as the `IFormatProvider` argument to the [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130977.aspx):

```
(decimal) Convert.ChangeType(a, typeof(decimal), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 5):

The conversion is most likely done using a culture that uses the period as thousands separator instead of decimal separator.

Specify the culture when you convert the value:

```
Convert.ToDecimal(a, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 3):

The following code

```
 string s = "40.00";
 decimal d = (decimal)Convert.ChangeType(s, typeof(decimal));
```

makes d = 40. This looks fine for me. What is your issue exactly?

Edit:
 It seems you might have an issue with the culture used. 
 Do this for conversion:

```
string s = "40.00";
decimal d = (decimal)Convert.ChangeType(s, typeof(decimal), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: The issue, as always, is that `.` is not always the decimal separator.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan what sort of creepy culture is that :/

Comment: At least in Russian, point is thousands separator and decimal separator is comma: "1.000,1". As values selarator ';' is used.